# Iterating over a list of integers and joining items based on a condition

Tags: python, string, list, integer, iteration

I am attempting to iterate over a list of integers and to join them based on a condition using the python standard library. For example, I have a list of integers that looks as such:

```
listOfIntegers = [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9]
```

I would like to iterate through this list and combine values such that the result would be a string of the form:

```
result = '000-20-4-60-8000-1-9'
```

(where the dashes are included). The condition for this is that if the preceding number is not equal to zero a dash must be placed in front of it. If the next value is equal to zero it is joined to the end of the value before it.

Comment: What have you done? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward approach, building a string from the list of integers, followed by a simple regex replacement:

```py
listOfIntegers = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9]
inp = ''.join([str(x) for x in listOfIntegers])
result = re.sub(r'(?<=.)(?=[^\D0])', '-', inp)
print(result)  # 100-20-4-60-8000-1-9
```

Comment: Concatenation is what i've found others did in order to solve problems similar to this. In fact I'm pretty sure I've seen a solution very similar to this. I suppose one detail I failed to mention is that the values within this list of integers has the ability to change to any value from 0-9. What happens if the second entry of the list is now a 1. is there anyway to automate the concatenation process such that the result would now be #0-10-20-4-60-8000-1-9

Comment: @Dugg I have updated with another answer.

Comment: This as well as another answer above works great, however, if the list is changed such that the first entry of the list is now a 1, the result is #-100-20-4-60-8000-1-9 where a dash is unfortunately placed at the very beginning. Is there any way to eliminate that from happening such that the result would be #100-20-4-60-8000-1-9? Also you have been a ton of help so far with this. Thank You!

Comment: @42Dugg Check the updated answer.  We can add a positive lookbehind which asserts that dashes are only added for characters other than the first one.

Answer (score 2):

This would help:
(Considering numbers are positive in the given list)

```
def join(lst):
    return "".join(list(map(lambda x: str(-x), lst))).lstrip('-')

listOfIntegers = [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9]
print(join(listOfIntegers)) # 000-20-4-60-8000-1-9
```

**The process:**

1. Convert each element to negative, in which:

   - `9` becomes `-9`
   - `0` has no effect as `-0` is `0` in python
2. Then convert them into strings and join them
3. Make sure to remove Trailing `hyphen`, in our case `lstrip('-')` helps us with that.

Comment: Please note what you did and why it worked. This makes it better for others who may come across this page later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
listOfIntegers = [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9]

for i in listOfIntegers:
    if i != 0:
        print("-" + str(i), end="")
    else:
        print(str(i), end="")
```

For each item in the list, we check if the item is not equal to 0. If it isn't equal to 0, we print out the item with a dash in front of it, and use the `end` parameter to avoid new lines. If it is 0, we simply print out the item.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop:

```
def func(nums):
    result = ''
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num != 0 and i != 0:
            result += '-'
        result += str(num)
    return result
```

Comment: This works out great, however, if the list is changed such that the first entry of the list is now a 1, the result is #-100-20-4-60-8000-1-9 where a dash is unfortunately placed at the very beginning. Is there any way to eliminate that from happening such that the result would be #100-20-4-60-8000-1-9? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for missing that edge case. We can simply add a condition to skip the first number. I've edited the code accordingly.